# Calculates the volts from CS5530 24-bit AD converter

Tags: adc, analog, spi

I have this circuit (Power supply is 5V):

[image: CS5530 Circuit]

The problem is: How to convert the values to Volts? I get the digital value in 24-bit from spi interface, but I don't know the minimum and maximun voltages to calculate a conversion.

Thanks.

---

SOLUTION: The 24-bit represents ~39mV span (0 = 0, ~39mV = 16777215), Due to my configuration (unipolar input)

The 39mV of span should reside in 1.6 to 3.4, for example:

- can be 2.000 to 2.039 Volts;
- can be 2.500 to 2.539 Volts;
- and others...

Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: What part(s) of the data sheet don't you understand? It would seem a bit early to conclude it's working well if you have not been able to interpret the data.

Comment: I'd guess 0x000000 = VREF- (0V) and 0xFFFFFF = VREF+ (5V). But reading the data sheet is better than guessing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The +ref is tied to +5V and the -ref is tied to 0V - this means your input signal range is 5V but, there is an analogue stage with a fixed gain of 64 so this means your input range is 78.125mV.

Additionally the spec sheet says: -

> The common-mode plus signal range of the instrumentation amplifier is
>   (VA-) + 1.6 V to (VA+) - 1.6 V.

This basically tells you that your inputs can reside between 1.6V and 3.4V (nominally centred about 2.5V). Section 2.3.4 also tells you that the fixed gain of 64 might be 128 depending on bit VRS being set or cleared.

So, depending how you set VRS bit you'll have a full scale input of either 78.125mV or half of this and that is what your ADC value represents. That's how it looks to me anyway.

To get sensible readings your input voltages need to be within the common mode voltage range of 1.6V to 3.4V - this is important.

Comment: The VRS is 0, so ((VREF+)–(VREF-))/(64Y) = 39,0625mV, ok? Need only to convert the bits considering the range 1.6V to 3.4V?

Comment: Do you know if the map function from arduino can solve it? For example map(x=6000, in_min=0, in_max=2^24, out_min=1.6, out_max=3.4), considering that floats are acceptable.  Thanks

Comment: @LeandroIP I'm no expert on arduino code dude but good luck and if it doesn't appear to be correct, try using a potential divider from the 5V rail to generate two voltages that are the correct distance apart as a means of calibrating it.

Answer (score 0):

Also using 24bit ADC with Vref hooked up to power practically gives you way lower effective number of bits, so your 24bit ADC becomes 16bit or less due to the noise contamination of Vref input.
Also CS5530 datasheet has calibration section.